# How to get a personal access token for dotnet-nuget from the command line?

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have an ADO repo that uses .NET 7 for a C# solution that has dependencies to pull from a corporate nuget feed.  There's a way of getting the Personal Access Tokens (PAT) from the web UI by-hand, but there's another way to get the same from the command line. Specifically a command I would run before `dotnet build` that would pop Edge up to do an authentication action before closing.

For different NPM repos/projects, I can do the PAT acquisition via `npm install -g vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false && vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc -f`

**The question:** Can I use the latter, then copy the relevant piece out of .npmrc to something that dotnet.exe will pick up?  Or is there a *canonical* dotnet.exe command line incantation for the same?  I'm on Windows 10 Thinkpad, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from your question I assume you're using AzureDevOps as a host for the corporate nuget feed. So that you likely have installed [Azure Artifact Credential Provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#azure-artifacts-credential-provider). If not, you would need to.
With all the above the **--interactive** switch of either [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#options) or [dotnet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore#options) commands will do the authentication trick for the nuget feed. And there is no need to manually retrieve PAT with this approach.

Comment: In my case I do need to manually retrieve the PAT for fetching a nuget package inside a `docker build` command => https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md#using-the-azure-artifact-credential-provider